# How to add my unrecorded GitHub contributions to my updated settings

Tags: github

I've done a lot of work in our company GitHub org, but I did not notice that I am not a contributor in any of the repositories I have worked on. when I check my GitHub profile and see the graph, it has all my contributions green light, but when I check each repos, I am not one of the contributors.

I searched the internet and I found out that I haven't set up my local identity
`git config --global user.email` and it is empty.

I fixed it, and new pushes and commits are now showing, but my problem now and my question is; is it still possible to have my previous contributions appear in the repositories tied up with my email?

Comment: It's possible, but practical? not really. You'll have to rebase/branch-filter each repo.

Comment: The GitHub contribution graph is determined *by* GitHub, according to GitHub rules; nothing Git does here really matters except that GitHub uses Git. For the GitHub rules, see https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-settings-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile (pay particular attention to how they use email addresses!).